# Blackberry Eclipse Plugin - cannot generate cod file or see BB properties

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I am using the BB eclipse plugin to create a BlackBerry app. I made some changes to my app but they were not reflected in the simulator. So I ran clean.bat and rebuilt the project. But now the project's cod file is not getting generated.

And if I try and view the BlackBerry project properties for the Project, I get an error saying the window contains invalid values and it doesn't let me see the BB properties of the project.

The only solution I've found in the support forums is to create a new project and copy the whole code to this workspace. But that doesn't look like a very good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the blackberry eclipse plugin. I had the same problem and "fixed" it creating a new project.

Sometimes it works launching the simulator and erasing the application in the simulated blackberry. Another trick is to delete .jar, .jad and .cod refresh and then clean all.

The last tricks that also works is to open the same workspace with the Blackberry IDE and it may repair it.

Sorry, I don't have a definite solution but I hope you can solve your problem with one of the tips.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have written to BB support asking whether it is a bug

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some steps as:-

1. Delete deliverables folder.
2. Remove all .jad files from your system. Search all .jad files in system.
3. Go to eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\simulator and run clean.bat. It will reset the clean simulator.
4. Clean all projects from workspace.